# How to use C++ subscribe to a custom msg array published by Python

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use python publish a msg like this:

```
InfoData.msg
    int32 Num
    string color
    string name
 InfoDataArray.msg
   InfoData[] Infos
```

Now I want to use C++ subscribe the `InfoDataArray.mag` and store in the Structure. how to do this ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324325/how-to-use-c++-subscribe-to-a-custom-msg-array-published-by-python/) by [ffzj](https://answers.ros.org/users/41923/ffzj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
Please tell us what you've tried yourself already.

We're here to help, but not to write your code for you.

Susbcribers and publishers are language agnostic. It doesn't matter whether you "publish in Python" or "subscribe in C++". The data will arrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First place to start would be: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/ros_tutorials/kinetic-devel/roscpp_tutorials/listener/listener.cpp (from ROS Wiki Tutorial). The callback is where you will handle the parsing of the message and subsequent storing into your array I think.

---

Originally posted by [cantrelldynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/41925/cantrelldynamics/) with karma: 16 on 2019-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0